# Entity framework code first error only when my sqlserver database does not exist

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am only getting this error when I don't create the database in SQL server. If I create the empty database in SQL server, then it will create all my code first models.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information:
The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the `OnModelCreating` method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently.
Note that instance members of `DbContext` and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Show your DbContext